# Using viewport to have mobile friendly websites

Tags: html, css

[I'm working on a website for a small festival](http://www.ambergoodwin.com/ooo/index2.html) for a friend, but I'm trying to work with mobile browsing WITHOUT fluid layouts, ect. It's just a website that I want to use the classic viewport script so it will be at the minimum zoom when a mobile device comes to it.

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="450, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

That's what I have now however I have tried this way as well.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Yet every single time I come to the site on my mobile device it's zoomed in so you can only see the logo.

What am I doing wrong?

Also there are 2 other things I've noticed when viewing on the phone. 
The footer background colour doesn't stretch all the way across (and it's no different if I have device-width OR width="XXX"). Yet the width of my footer is 100%. I don't understand what is happening here.

And I'm trying to put padding, or a space to the left and right of the content so the website isn't resting right up on the side of the window. I want to have space to the left and right. I've tried to put this on the html tag but it only applies it to the left side??

I've gone to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag & http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html and other websites and can't understand what might be happening in any of these cases.

Any help, advice, direction or guidance is VERY much appreciated.

Comment: Which devices have you tested on? We've discovered different Android devices, in particular, deal with (or sometimes ignore) the viewport meta tag in odd ways.

Comment: Right now I'm testing on iPhone, Android and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the background issue try adding this:

```
body {
       min-width: 1024px;
}
```

You have the top sections of the page inside a container with an explicit width (960px), which is why you aren't having an issue with them. The footer however is on its own without an explicit width set. You could also just enclose it in the same div with the id 'container' you used for the rest of the page.

This should also fix your padding issue. Make sure you are adding it to the content containers. For example:

```
#main {
       padding: 0 1.5em;
}
```

As for the zooming issue, I am not seeing it on an iPad or an iPhone. Since you are not doing any sort of fluidity or responsiveness this is what you should be using. What initial-scale=1 is doing is zooming it into to its actual width, not fitting it to your screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

You might want to check out this question: [Android ignores maximum-scale when using fixed-width viewport meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316836/android-ignores-maximum-scale-when-using-fixed-width-viewport-meta-tag) for the Android issue. I don't have an Android device handy to test so I don't want to give you incorrect info on that part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the container that the top bar is in as it's a background image on the html tag, so once I place the max-width: 1024px; on the body it makes everything fit in the first 1024px (as I've now told it can't be larger than 1024, which I dont want). The padding on the main div worked, so thank you for that!

Comment: So far for the viewport scripts, I'm having no luck, or at least with my iPhone. When I have this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> it works when I use this one <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> it zooms in again. So I'm not sure why it's doing that. My boyfriend has an android and I get him to test on it all the time and so far no matter what I do it's always zoomed in for him. Any advice?

Comment: Updated my answer, typed a bit too fast, sorry.